# Working with couchdb and push to git repo in a angularjs project

Tags: angularjs, git, couchdb

I'm working in a project that using couchdb, it's the first time I use couchdb. The process we have is to edit couchdb file, commit and push it to our git repo, and run a curl command to update the row into couchdb, but we can edit the couchdb row in couchdb interface too.

Is this process correct? How can I ensure that files in couchdb are in the same version that I have in git, if an user changed the couchdb file through interface?

I looked into tutorials to how to do this management, someone have an indication?

Answer (score 0):

When you open the couchdb interface make sure you are pointing to files in the git repository on your system.

One way to check is:
1. Make changes using couchdb interface, dont commit or anything
2. Open the location that houses your Git repo of couchdb files and run `git status`. It should show the files you modified in interface as changed. If not, then your interface is pointing to files stored at some other location

Comment: I'm using Futon. You mean there's a way to futon talk to my git repo? Where I could found it on Futon?